# Access of properties of HTMLMediaElement Interface in some another package

Tags: html, typescript, dom, media, w3c

In a **package A**, there is an interface named **HTMLMediaElement** which had some properties i.e.,

```
HAVE_METADATA: number;
HAVE_CURRENT_DATA: number;
HAVE_NOTHING: number;
NETWORK_NO_SOURCE: number;
HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA: number;
NETWORK_EMPTY: number;
NETWORK_LOADING: number;
NETWORK_IDLE: number;
HAVE_FUTURE_DATA: number;
```

The **HTMLMediaElement** interface is implemented by **Video** class, which returns the value of these properties as:

```
get HAVE_CURRENT_DATA(): number {
        return 4;
}
```

**HTMLMediaElement interface and Video class both are exported.**

[https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#dom-media-have_current_data:~:text=4.8.11.7-,Ready%20states,-media.readyState](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#dom-media-have_current_data:%7E:text=4.8.11.7-,Ready%20states,-media.readyState)

HTMLMediaElement interface reference:
https://github.com/TypeStrong/tscs/blob/master/lib/node_modules/TypeScript/bin/lib.dom.d.ts#L8840

What I want is,

I am having another **package B** (where I am importing HTMLMediaElement interface and Video class), and want to access the HTMLMediaElement properties like,

`HTMLMediaElement.HAVE_CURRENT_DATA` as globally in package B.

I don't want to access these properties (HAVE_CURRENT_DATA, HAVE_NOTHING, etc.) by Video class object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert Interface HTMLMediaElement to abstract class and add abstract keyword to properties and methods (so it will work like interface).
Add static keyword to readonly Properties:

```
static readonly HAVE_CURRENT_DATA : number = 0;
```

Note: not sure but it works for me, you don't need to change the subclass defintion from “implements” to “extend” class.